# How do I vertically change the volume

Tags: jquery, html, css

I managed to change my originally-horizontal volume slider to vertical style in CSS, however the volume slider still functions as if it was still horizontal, i.e I have to click horizontally in order to change the volume, and not vertically.

HTML

```
<div class="jp-volume-bar wolf-volume">
                        <div class="jp-volume-bar-value"></div>
                    </div>
```

CSS

```
    .wolf-jplayer-playlist .wolf-volume{
    display:none
}

.wolf-jplayer-playlist .jp-volume-bar{
    position:absolute;
    height: 50px;
  width: 5px;
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    top:85px;
    left:278px
}

.wolf-jplayer-playlist .jp-volume-bar:hover{
    cursor:pointer
}

.wolf-jplayer-playlist .jp-volume-bar-value{
    height: 300px;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: #db2537
}
```

Jquery (quite long code):

```
http://djacademynegypt.com/wp-content/plugins/wolf-jplayer/assets/js/min/jquery.jplayer.concat.min.js?ver=2.1.7.3
```

Comment: It's kinda hard to debug your code when you don't post any...

Comment: Some code snippets of what you have done would be helpful.

Comment: While the live site is a good thing to post (saves us the trouble of making a JSFiddle) you **also** need to provide the code that you believe is causing the issue. That way, we can test and compare.

Comment: Ok someone helped me with a vertical volume slider and it slides exactly how I want, except that it does not change the volume or anything it has no effect on the volume.. somebody please help me! the live website is djacademynegypt.com

Comment: Can you make a Fiddle so as to showcase the issue?

Comment: the issue is on the live website www.djacademynegypt.com I think this can be better and more satisfying? the issue is that the volume controller is horizontal when clicking to change the volume, I need to change that to vertical..

Answer (score 2):

use [jQuery UI Slider](http://jqueryui.com/slider/):

[example](https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/slider/slider-vertical.html)

To really change the volume you have to interact with the [jPlayer API](http://jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-volume) within the 'slide' callback:

```
$(".jp-volume-bar").slider({
   orientation: 'vertical',
   slide: function(event, ui) {      
      $(".jp-volume-bar-value").text(ui.value);
      $("#jpId").jPlayer("volume", ui.value/100); // jpId is the player id
   }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="jp-volume-bar wolf-volume"></div>
<div class="jp-volume-bar-value"></div>
```

[full example here.](http://jsfiddle.net/9fgp7jp0/2)

Comment: How? Do you also want to share how this magically changes the volume? This is an incomplete answer.

Comment: CodeFreaks,... why don't you CSS style it as you like then?

Comment: Ok I will style it, but can you tell me how do I "interact" it with the WolfJplayer API within the slider callback, please? I don't know how to do that.

Comment: I checked their API and edited the code for you...

Comment: Hey it doesn't work.. http://djacademynegypt.com/

Comment: Create a jsbin ou jsfiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/f5Ltjcao/ result won't show up? o.o I kinda never used jsfiddle before tho

Comment: include jQuery and jPlayer using the left pane.

Comment: I can't, look at the page source and you will get what I mean, <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA for example. How do I include that? I thought using Firebug on the live website was enough

Comment: "Frameworks & Extensions" >>> include "jQuery (edge)"
"External Resources" >>> include https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jplayer/2.9.2/jplayer/jquery.jplayer.js

Comment: Ok I've done that and it's still not showing up http://jsfiddle.net/f5Ltjcao/2/, I'm sorry to be bothering you with this bro, I'm so grateful for your efforts. Maybe you can try it yourself?

Comment: full example here: http://jsfiddle.net/9fgp7jp0/2
check if it's what you need